# iPhone Form Styles

Tags: iphone, css, html, forms

OK, I'm not exactly a developer but I'm building a website here: http://www.theycallmeben.com

The contact form at the bottom is the first I've ever built, using simple HTML and php. What's driving me crazy is that the form's styles on my iPhone are different than on the web. The fields have rounded edges and the submit button is using an image the doesn't even exist in my code (I don't think).

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/noEhu.png

I have no specific CSS styles in my media queries for this form, only the styles that are being used with the form as viewed on a computer. Why would it be different?

Any ideas? Sorry if this is silly...I'm a self-taught guy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, possibly?

```
textarea, select, button, input{
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Also, using a CSS Reset may solve the problem. I like http://html5reset.org/.

Comment: Ah OK, good call. That worked for the input fields but that strange submit button is still there. I'll check the code again and look into the CSS reset, although I've never done that before!